# Excessive TableStatus wait in dynamodb

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

i have some 200+ tables in my dynamodb. Since all my tables have `localSecondaryIndexes` defined, i have to ensure that no table is in the `CREATING` status, at the time of my `CreateTable()` call.

While adding a new table, i list all tables and iterate through their names, firing `describeTable()` calls one by one. On the returned data, i check for `TableStatus` key. Each `describeTable()` call takes a second. This implies an average of 3 minute waiting time before creation of each table. So if i have to create 50 new tables, it takes me around 4 hours.

How do i go about optimizing this? i think that a  `BatchGetItem()` call works on stuff *inside* the table and not table-metadata. Can i do a bulk `describeTable()` call?

Comment: Why do you have to ensure that no table is in `CREATING` status?  Couldn't you try to create the table, and then backoff and wait 5 seconds if it fails before trying again?

Comment: That is what i did, eventually. i wonder if there is an elegant method to do this.

Answer (score 1):

It is enough that you wait until the last table you created becomes ACTIVE. Run DescribeTable on that last created table with a few seconds interval.